# Where have I gone wrong in this Extended Euclidean Algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**1. "Use the Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor of 633 and 255"**

633 = 2 x 255 + 123

255 = 2 x 123 + 9

123 = 13 x 9 + 6

9 = 1 x 6 + 3

6 = 2 x 3 + 0

Therefore gcd is 3.

**2. "Find integers x and y such that 633x + 255y = 6, or explain why none exist."**

3 = 9 - (1 x 6)

3 = 9 - (1 x (123 - 13 x 9)) = -1 x 123 + 14 x 9

3 = -1 x 123 + 14 x (255 - 2 x 123) = 14 x 255 - 29 x 123

3 = 14 x 255 - 29 x (633 - 2 x 255) = -29 x 633 - 17 x 255

3 = -29 x 633 + 72 x 255

6 = -58 x 633 + 144 x 255

These numbers don't work in the answer, what have I done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers $x = -58$ and $y = 144$ (that you found above) do work.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I plugged them in incorrectly the first time. My mistake, sorry for wasting your time.